# SSIS - Replace Dynamic SQL With Variables

Tags: ssis

in my dataflow task I have OLEDB Source with the following query:

```
SELECT  am.Code AS MeterCode
       ,am.Code AS NewMeterCode
       ,am.Description AS NewMeterDescription
       ,mr.TagName
       ,mr.RunHours
       ,mr.DateTo AS DateRead
FROM    [19-AIS-004\VIJEOHISTORIAN].VijeoHistorianCPSData.dbo.RunHours AS mr
        INNER JOIN dbo.astMeters AS am ON mr.TagName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = am.Code
```

the table 'mr' is the linked server table where i'm getting the Tagname, Runhours and DateTo and join it with astMeters table in order to import  data from mr table to am table.
my problem is since the package is deployed in the remote server via vpn I need a way which I can created string parameter for the this table '[19-AIS-004\VIJEOHISTORIAN].VijeoHistorianCPSData.dbo.RunHours'.

Answer (score 0):

Build your entire query as an SSIS string variable, and in your OLEDB Source, choose `SQL Query From Variable` and select the string variable that holds your query.